Trying to Build Basic IEPE Circuit: Facing issue with the Op-amp
I am building a simple IEPE Circuit for this IEPE Microphone but I am facing issues with the Op-amp. I have connected the signal output from 22uF capacitor to non-inverting configurated Op- amp OPA227UA using resistors Rf=56kohm and R1=1.14kohm giving me a gain of 50.
But now when I connect the Opamp's output to arduino's Analog Pin A5, the Serial monitor gives me constant values (850+) and then sometimes falls down to 30-150.
I cant figure whether my circuit is wrong or the microphone is not working.

const int microphonePin = A5;
int micvalue = 0;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  micvalue = analogRead(microphonePin);
  Serial.print("Analog Signal Value = ");
  Serial.println(micvalue);
  delay(500);
}



That 22 μF capacitor isn't doing anything; you don't have any path for current through it. Remember that op-amp inputs are very nearly open circuits.

The circuit you need has to refer the signal to the center of the analog input pin voltage range. On an Arduino Nano, a 2.5V center voltage is reasonable.
The 2.5V is generated by the voltage divider R2-R3, and bypassed by C2. That way, the reference voltage has a much lower source impedance than 24kΩ at audio frequencies. This lets us use large resistors to limit idle current consumption.
R1 establishes the DC reference voltage on the right side of the input decoupling capacitor C1. The low-pass cutoff of the C1-R1 filter is 21Hz - about as low as you'd want to go with a general purpose microphone.
The op-amp amplifies the AC input signal with a gain of +48.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
With a 20mVpp 1kHz sine input signal, the output voltage looks like this:

The circuit needs just two resistor values - 1kΩ and 47kΩ. The values are not critical - 5% resistors (gold band) will work just fine.
The 5V op-amp supply needs decoupling as per the datasheet. I haven't shown it.

sorry for the late reply, is it alright instead of 100nf capacitor I use a 1uf capacitor since that's the minimum I have. also if there's a sound what change will i see in the output?

nvm i luckily found 100nf Capacitor

I couldnt find any info regarding the capacitor at opamp supply. Lets say if i connect 100nf capacitor, the connection will  be from 5v to the 100nf capacitor and then to v+ pin of the opamp?

So I have made the connections, with the 5v supply connected to the opamp's vcc and a 100nf capacitor from the supply to the common ground. I also converted the analog values to voltage values.
This is what normally the output fluctuates around 1.4 - 1.6v

And when I make some sound (table knocking sound), this is the output i get
'''Analog Signal voltage = 1.89
Analog Signal voltage = 1.22
Analog Signal voltage = 1.31
Analog Signal voltage = 1.41
Analog Signal voltage = 0.09
Analog Signal voltage = 1.47
Analog Signal voltage = 4.05
Analog Signal voltage = 1.64
Analog Signal voltage = 0.07
Analog Signal voltage = 1.55'''

@Brendan * The opamp output voltage, without any input signal, should be 2.5V.

@Raonoke yes but unfortunately the microphone is not working properly as the diaphragm could be lose, meaning the diaphragm doesn't move at all and therefore I am only getting low signals and when I tap on the microphone the it gives me 4volts. There are several instances were there 2.5volts as seen here------- Output------ Analog Signal voltage = 1.03 Analog Signal voltage = 3.79 Analog Signal voltage = 2.50 Analog Signal voltage = 0.10 Analog Signal voltage = 2.70 Analog Signal voltage = 2.11 Analog Signal voltage = 4.04----

The output signal coming from your microphone will be a bipolar signal.A typical  representation is given below.

In your circuit the opamp is working with a single supply.So you need to provide a level shifting circuit to take care of the negative half of the
signal coming from the MIC.
You can use the circuit given below for making a reference voltage.Design R1
and R2 as per your needs.



Unfortunately I only have a single opamp is there any alternate way?

Try to create a reference using only two resistors.

You mean to create a voltage divider of 5 volts dividing it to 2.5 volts and then directly connect it to the non inverting input of the opamp

You need to level shift your input.The amount of shift required,you can decide.

ok i did the level shift as stated above , when there is no sound or impulse it gives a constant value around 787 - 796. and when I give an impulse or sound it goes below to 547-710

I think the microphone is causing issue as i need to tap on microphone itself to see the signal shift and there seems to be no signal shift when creating sound a bit far away from microphone

The complete circuit is shown below. The OPA2277 has no rail-to-rail output so you need to be careful with the input level (max. 50mVpp) with a supply voltage of 5V. The reference voltage for the ADC should be 5V.


The netlist of the circuit is good. The schematic rendition of it is barely readable.

but in the website it mentions that it has a rail-to-rail output?
https://www.mouser.in/ProductDetail/Texas-Instruments/OPA2277UA-2K5?qs=7nS3%252BbEUL6s9EB8NhHXTsw%3D%3D

@Brendan * The datasheet doesn't mention R2R-out.

Alright. Then I will make the said connections. Also I don't have 47 uf and 100nf capacitor. I only have 1,10,22uf capacitors.
Are they really necessary, I have to oder them and might take some time.

Also can you suggest me any resources or books where I could learn more about these circuits.

Component values are not set in stone, use the next best you have.

Since the output is bipolar signal, how can i show whether a signal is high or low? like a normal voltage based sensor ?

@Raonoke   check the new answer by me

@Brendan * Reference voltage output is 2.5V. Voltages above 2.5V will be "high level"and below that will be considered "low level".

So I have followed the circuit design posted by "Kuba hasn't forgotten Monica". I have also converted the analog values to voltage values for easy understanding.
Conclusion : The voltage spike is when the sound is made. But the sound only being tapping on the microphone, it doesn't pickup any other sound like clapping, this could mean the membrane of the microphone is loose thus concluding that the microphone is faulty.
Circuit Design

The output graph

